# Stars and Bars vs PIE

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I randomly made up this question so I could check:

> There are $3$ kids and $6$ gifts, how many ways to distribute so that each kid has **at least one gift.**

Obviously,

$**|**|**$ there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ solutions by stars-and-bars.

**PIE approach:**

There are $3$ choices for each of the $6$ gifts $= 3^6$.

Let the kids be $ABC$, it is possible that $AB, BC, AC$ got all the gifts and one group didnt so:

$3^6 - 3(2^6)$

But then that also includes $A, B, C$ only getting the gifts (twice for each) so we add $3$.

$3^6 - 3(2^6) + 3 = 540$.

> Obviously, the first one has to be correct, but why doesnt the second approach work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because in the second version you treat the gifts as different and in the first version you treat them as equivalent.

Comment: very interesting. So if I treated the gifts as the same even in the second version, how would I go about this?

Comment: You could just assume one gift per child as given and distribute the remaining three - you again get the number of possibilities by stars-and-bars, but only using 3 stars.

Comment: @Amad27: There are $\binom{6+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to distribute $6$ equivalent gifts to $k$ children, so $\binom82=28$, $\binom71=7$ and $\binom60=1$ ways to distribute them to $3$, $2$ and $1$ children, respectively. So inclusion-exclusion gives $28-3\cdot7+3\cdot1=10$, in agreement with your first, direct approach.

Comment: @Joriki, a question. If you considered the gifts different then is $AB$ a different way of giving than $BA$? (where $A,B$ are gifts)?

Comment: @Amad27: There seems to be a widespread misconception that there is something like right and wrong about what should be considered as different / distinguishable. There isn't; you first have to define what the "different ways" that you want to count are, before you count them. Depending on what you're interested in, the order in which you give the presents to the children may or may not matter. Note that for probabilities it's an entirely different question, which is not about arbitrary definitions of distinguishability but about justifiable applications of the principle of indifference.

Answer (score 1):

Another way by PIE would be:

There are $3^6=729$ possibilities.

If one kid gets 6 gifts: 3 possibilities.

If one kid gets 5 gifts and another 1 gift: ${6 \choose 1}\times 6=36$ possibilities.

If one kid gets 4 gifts and another 2 gifts: ${6 \choose 2}\times 6=90$ possibilities.

If one kid gets 3 gifts and another 3 gifts: ${6 \choose 3}\times 3=60$ possibilities.

Therefore there remain $729-189=540$ possibilities.